# Asterisk ARI - Pass channel to Stasis before Ringing

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

## My goal

Pass an incoming call directly to Stasis and allow the app to decide whether to play a ringing or busy tone to the caller.

## The problem

With my ARI app, if I omit the `same => n,Ringing` line from my dialplan, the Stasis app returns an error if the caller hangs up. I can have a call hang without any early media, until I pass a `channel.play()` command, via the ARI.

This solution has 2 issues:

1. The Stasis app receives a second StasisStart when the caller hangs up, returning a `Channel not found` error.
2. There is no command for `channel.busy`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

My only option that I can currently see is to ensure that **all** users have voicemail and a busy tone is never played.  Not everyone wants / likes voicemail and it is not ethical to answer the call and play a busy tone, without the caller knowing that their call is connected.

## Update

Using the following dialplan, I can get this to work in the desired way (plays busy to a user if they're not available), but with an error:

#### extensions.conf

```
[public]
exten => _.,1,NoOp()
same  =>    n,Stasis(myStasisApp, ${SIP_HEADER(to)})
same  =>    n,Busy(10)
same  =>    n,Hangup()
```

#### myApp.js

```
// The user is available
channel.ring();

// The user is busy
channel.continueInDialplan();
```

### Error

Another StasisStart is sent when the caller hangs up, followed by:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: {
  "message": "Channel not found"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We faced the same problem and lost precious time finding out the reason so I'm sharing the solution here and maybe it will help.

---

**extensions.conf**

```
[public]
exten => _.,1,NoOp()
same  =>    n,Stasis(myStasisApp)
same  =>    n,Hangup()
```

When Asterisk receive a call, it will start the stasis app.

1. Create a Bridge.
2. Add the incomming `channel A` in this bridge.
3. Create a new outgoing `channel B` from your ari app with `POST /channels/create`.
4. Add the outgoing `channel B` in that bridge.
5. Dial from `channel B` the destination, where both of the channels
   are in the same bridge with `POST /channels/{channelId}/dial`

Now, you will be able to see a new ARI Dial events with Ringing and Answer.

For the Hangup, you will receive Channels end events with Hangup Cause Code not a text like 17 for busy

[Asterisk Hangup Cause Mappings](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Cause+Mappings)

It's simpler to originate a channel (Asterisk version 13) instead of create and dial (Asterisk version 14) but you will not have the early media or a full control on that channel because it's created by Asterisk and not the ARI app so this channel will start sending event back to ARI when the call start and not before.

[Asterisk 14 ARI: Create, Bridge, Dial.](https://blogs.asterisk.org/2016/08/24/asterisk-14-ari-create-bridge-dial/)

[ARI and Channels: Manipulating Channel State](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ARI+and+Channels%3A+Manipulating+Channel+State)

This thread helped us a lot:

[Re: ARI: add channel to bridge immediatelly    after originate action](https://www.spinics.net/lists/asterisk-app-dev/msg00855.html)

.

.

.

*Have fun ! and Hope this will help.

/ohammami*

Comment: Thanks for this. It makes interesting reading. What I am hoping to do is present a Busy Here back to the originating endpoint, without having to create additional channels and bridges

Comment: From my understanding, you can do it with delete https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+14+Channels+REST+API#Asterisk14ChannelsRESTAPI-hangup with reason `busy`

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks